# Best query for scrabble in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table with 5 million rows.
Want to write query that will help scrabble players.
There are 8 letters 2 of which can be wildcards.

Number of possible combinations is `itertools.permutations(letters)`, which is `8!` at worst case.
Suppose that word is `ex*ampl*`
Then I write the query `SELECT * from words where word like 'exampl_' or name like 'ex_ample'...`

But there are `8!` or clauses and query is too slow.
Is there a faster way?

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have a git for this or something. It sounds great!

Comment: No. I don't have.

Comment: Use N-grams (postgres has a trigram extension)

Answer (score 2):

You're querying for words where the number of characters in the word *but not in the hand* is less than the number of
available wildcards.

To find the set of extra characters in a candidate word:

```
-- characters in the word
SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array(word, ''))
-- except those in the hand
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT unnest('{E, X, A, M, P, L}' :: CHAR [])
```

You can use this to select words where the set of extra characters is less than the number of wildcards available. In
your example the hand contains the characters `{E, X, A, M, P, L}` and two wildcards, so the query would be:

```
SELECT word
FROM words
WHERE
  (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array(word, ''))
        EXCEPT ALL
        SELECT unnest('{E, X, A, M, P, L}' :: CHAR [])
      ) extra
  ) <= 2
;
```

This requires a table scan, so it won't be fast. One way to speed it up would be to de-normalise a bit; store the
words as character arrays and you will be able to take advantage of a GIN index and use the postgres array operators
to narrow down the set of words to search.

With an indexed `chars` column:

```
-- Add a chars column to the words table
ALTER TABLE words ADD COLUMN chars CHAR [];

-- Populate it
UPDATE words SET chars = regexp_split_to_array(word, '');
ALTER TABLE words ALTER COLUMN chars SET NOT NULL;

-- A GIN index on the chars column
CREATE INDEX ix_word_chars ON words USING GIN (chars);

-- An index on word length
CREATE INDEX ix_word_length ON words (char_length(word));
```

You can use the postgres `@>` array operation to quickly find anagrams of a word:

```
SELECT word
FROM words
WHERE
  chars @> '{E, X, A, M, P, L, E}' :: CHAR []
  AND
  char_length(word) = 7
  AND
  (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT unnest(chars)
        EXCEPT ALL
        SELECT unnest('{E, X, A, M, P, L, E}' :: CHAR [])
      ) extra
  ) = 0
;
```

**Note:** Even if though there are no wildcards in the above example, we still need to filter out words with extra
characters. The `@>` operator just checks that the array on the left contains all of the elements of the array on the
right; it does not check cardinality, so words with repeated letters will match.

Extending this to find words with varying combinations of the input characters requires more work. Noting that a word
of length seven must match some combination of five characters from the hand (plus the two wildcards), we can filter
the candidate set against those combinations (helpfully provided by python's `itertools.combinations('EXAMPL', 5)`):

```
WITH combinations (combination) AS (
  VALUES
    ('{E, X, A, M, P}' :: CHAR []),
    ('{E, X, A, M, L}' :: CHAR []),
    ('{E, X, A, P, L}' :: CHAR []),
    ('{E, X, M, P, L}' :: CHAR []),
    ('{E, A, M, P, L}' :: CHAR []),
    ('{X, A, M, P, L}' :: CHAR [])
)
SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM words w
  JOIN combinations c ON w.chars @> c.combination
WHERE
  char_length(word) = 7
  AND
  (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT unnest(chars)
        EXCEPT ALL
        SELECT unnest('{E, X, A, M, P, L}' :: CHAR [])
      ) extra
  ) <= 2;
```

Which can be extended to accommodate shorter words or fewer wildcards as required.

Comment: Please consider posting your answer in the form of a Q & A question / answer in the 'Database Administrators' forum. https://dba.stackexchange.com .  I've adapted this for my purposes here in 2021.